# Надо ли делать close()?

Tags: java

В случае конструкции ниже нужно ли вручную вызывать br.close(); , ибо вроде там же конструкция try with resources и по идее она сама сделает всё что нужно для того, чтобы высвободить ресурсы. Задаю вопрос, так как среда не подсказывает, что close здесь не нужен.

```
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(configFile))) {
            //TODO: )0
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
```

Comment: Не надо, само закроется.

Comment: Только вот когда именно закроется - это хороший вопрос. Может через долю секунды, а может через минуту. Для мелких проектов это абсолютно не важно. А для высоконагруженных уже может быть принципиальным.